# How to find the basis functions of a polynomial solved for boundary conditions?

Tags: polynomials, coefficients

```
ss=Sum[a[i]*x^i,{i,0,10}]; 
eq1=ss/.x->0 
eq2=ss/.x->1 
sol=Solve[{eq1==0,eq2==0}]; 
sol1=ss/.sol
```

How can I find the coefficients of `a[2],a[3],....,a[10]` which would be `(-x+x^2)`,`(-x+x^3)`,...`(-x+x^10)`.

Comment: To make the most of Mma.SE start by *taking the [tour] now*. It will **help us to help you** if you write an [excellent question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). [Edit](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimal working example** of code and data in **[formatted form](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help)**. As you receive **give back**, vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.Why not choosing a meaningful name?

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`Coefficient`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Coefficient.html)

```
s = Sum[a[i]*x^i, {i, 0, 10}]
(* a[0] + x a[1] + x^2 a[2] + x^3 a[3] + x^4 a[4] + x^5 a[5] + 
 x^6 a[6] + x^7 a[7] + x^8 a[8] + x^9 a[9] + x^10 a[10] *)

sol = Solve@{
   0 == s /. x -> 0,
   0 == s /. x -> 1
   }
(* {{a[0] -> 0, 
  a[10] -> -a[1] - a[2] - a[3] - a[4] - a[5] - a[6] - a[7] - a[8] - 
    a[9]}} *)

pol = s /. First@sol
(* x a[1] + x^2 a[2] + x^3 a[3] + x^4 a[4] + x^5 a[5] + 
 x^6 a[6] + x^7 a[7] + x^8 a[8] + 
 x^10 (-a[1] - a[2] - a[3] - a[4] - a[5] - a[6] - a[7] - a[8] - 
    a[9]) + x^9 a[9] *)

Table[
 Coefficient[pol, a[k], 1]
 , {k, 0, 10}]
(* {0, x - x^10, x^2 - x^10, x^3 - x^10, x^4 - x^10, x^5 - x^10,
  x^6 - x^10, x^7 - x^10, x^8 - x^10, x^9 - x^10, 0} *)
```